# System.Security.Authentication and System.Linq do not exist

Tags: c#, .net, linq, mono, monodevelop

In mono I have found that a number of .NET libraries apparently do not exist, even though they are listed as being present in the version of mono I am using. While I have been able to obtain many by editing the references list some, most notably System.Security.Authentication and System.Linq are not found.

I am using monodevelop 4.0.12 and building for mono/.NET 4.5 on linux mint.

Answer (score 0):

In Mono 4, Linq is part of System.Core:
http://www.go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.0&profile=4.0&assembly=System.Core

And according http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=N%3aSystem.Security, Authentication has not been implemented.